# Android: get images from device

Tags: android, image, cursor

I have nexus 4 device.
On the device there is a native app, called "Gallery".

I'm trying to implement my own application, which will display images from the device.
I want my application to display the same images that "Gallery" does.

Currently, "Gallery" shows me only 2 images, made by me with camera.

Here is code, where I'm trying to query those images:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
    null,
    null,
    null);

int imagesCount = cursor.getCount();
```

Now imagesCount == 15! Why 15? Am I doing something wrong? How do I query images that are displayed in "Gallery" app correctly?

Comment: are the images stored in your external sd card. because you are searching the external storage for images. For where i see it, should be using MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Comment: All photos stored on SD Card. SD card is external storage